# standalone script or as module?

Tags: python, perl, module, package

I have always a dilemma with the choice of making a module/package or keeping a script standalone.

I often write small scripts/programs in Perl or Python that do some work. Sometime I use the same subroutine in several programs but they are only small subroutines and here comes my dilemma.

If I keep my script standalone, anybody can run it without installing any packages. If it is a single file it can be used from anywhere. However, if I make a module, my users will need to install it before using my script. I will need to consider the exception that the dependent modules are not available and later, the users could encounter issues during the installation of the required modules.

So, in order to avoid dependencies issues. I prefer having a bit of redundancy and not using any additional packages (only if I can do it. Obviously I won't reimplement `XML::Twig` in all my scripts, but I could do it for a INI parser or a Perl to JSON converter).

Also, I usually put all my scripts in the same directory like `/usr/local/mycompany/bin`

What would be the best strategy to adopt for scripts/programs that not exceed 200 lines and that are be used by less than 20 people ?

EDIT:

I am not asking for personal opinion. I am only looking for a very pragmatic and rational answer from those who have a good programming experience.

To give you a more concrete example. I have a script that parse a configuration file in a proprietary format. This format is used by many people in my company. However only my scripts use my parser. I think I have only three choices:

1. Placing the parser (about 50 lines) in each of my 5 scripts.
2. Making a nice module that need to be installed in the Perl/Python distribution.
3. Using a standalone library located in the same directory of the other scripts.

Comment: I wonder if the folks over at http://programmers.stackexchange.com might have some insight.

Comment: Re. "If I keep my script standalone, anybody can run it without installing any packages." I write Perl scripts all the time that require installing modules, even though the scripts themselves are not modules. It seems like what you're really asking about is not whether you should write a script or a module, but whether you should avoid *external dependencies*. Which is still a subjective question that is entirely dependent on your company, who will be using the code, how it is distributed, who will be maintaining it, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False dilemma.  You can do both at once.

You can make a module that you will use in your scripts, and then when it comes time to deploy the scripts, include it with them.  Either include it as a local module file, or actually roll up the module and the script into a single file.

That way, your stuff does not require any modules to be installed separately.

Comment: Very interesting answer! Does it exists for Perl a tool that merge a program and its dependancies to a standalone package?

Comment: Yes, check [pp](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?pp)

Comment: Also [fatpack](https://metacpan.org/release/App-FatPacker).

Comment: What do you mean by "local module file"?

Comment: @AntoinePinsard You can put a `*.pm` file in any folder you like -- i.e. include it in the same folder as the `*.pl` file or a subfolder along with it.